# Amazon Web Services (aws) S3 - Restrict access to bucket based on host name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to grant/restrict access to a bucket based on host name. So every request coming from *.something.edu would be granted access. Basically I want to replicate Apaches `Allow from (partial) domain-name` https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This Apache feature uses DNS lookups to check that the client's IP address has a reverse-DNS entry matching the domain name in question, and that the forward entry for the hostname also points back to that IP.

> This configuration will cause Apache httpd to perform a double DNS lookup on the client IP address, regardless of the setting of the `HostnameLookups` directive. It will do a reverse DNS lookup on the IP address to find the associated hostname, and then do a forward lookup on the hostname to assure that it matches the original IP address. Only if the forward and reverse DNS are consistent and the hostname matches will access be allowed.

S3 does not directly support such a configuration.

If you can obtain the actual IP address ranges, you can allow access based on source IP (or deny access based on "not source IP") using bucket policy.  This does not support reverse DNS-based matching, but does support CIDR ranges.

See [Restricting Access to Specific IP Addresses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-3) in the Amazon S3 Developer Guide.

Requests not matching such a policy will see a generic Access Denied message that can't be customized.

Another alternative that would allow this logic to be implemented in a way equivalent to Apache's would be to attach a [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) distribution to the bucket, and then use a [Lambda@Edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html) Viewer Request trigger -- a small snippet of Node.JS JavaScript that runs in a Lambda function at the edge -- to do the DNS lookup and allow or deny access.

The [event structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html#lambda-event-structure-request) provides `event.Records[0].cf.request.clientIp`.  You'd need to do the two DNS lookups using Node.js's [`dns`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/dns.html) resolver and return a response signaling CloudFront with whether the request should be allowed or denied.  If denied, you can return a custom response up to 40KB in size, potentially explaining the denial.

Lambda@Edge trigger code runs in a managed containerized environment that tends to persist its global variables between invocations, so the DNS lookups could be cached in memory, avoiding the lookup on repeat invocations for the same viewer.  The nature of this "container reuse" is outside the scope of this answer.  It isn't guaranteed but occurs very frequently.